# Angular Content Security Policy violation in production on file upload

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I have an angular app where users can upload and submit images, when working locally everything works fine but once i built my project and hosted it i am getting Content Security Policy violation errors when i try to upload an image through a `file input` and showing a **preview** of the image.

here is an example of the errors i am getting:

```
Refused to load the image 'data:image/png;base64,/9j/...' because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'".
Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

the error shows immediately after the user chose a file using the file input inside the form and the preview image is shown as a broken link.

i tried implementing some CSP in my index.html meta tags like so:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self';" />`

but it did not work, is their some documentation you can recommend in order to understand my problem?

if you need any piece of code or more information please let me know, to be honest i am not sure what is causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: Can you show the headers of the request of the index? Isn't it your server that adds csp?

Comment: @captainhak i am sorry but i am fairly new to this, were can i find the headers? in order to deploy my app i build my angular project and upload the dist folder to azure "Static Web App"

Comment: In the web browser in the network section of the inspector (f12) , when you hit f5, click on the first row and you'll find the headers there, and there will certainly be a csp header

Comment: Okay i believe these are the headers :`content-security-policy
 default-src https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help? https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/2 and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes#default-headers
I don't have access to azure so I can't help more than pointing to resources, but maybe by following these resources, you'll have the ability to change the csp to fit your need.

Comment: Thank for the help i managed to remove the default headers and now it is working as expected !